# VBA TextBox Value to Range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling to do what I believe is a simple task

I have a textbox on a user form that contains a numeric value which I wish to be used as a row number reference in a range.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & TextBox1.Value).Select
```

This fails with the error "Select Method of Range Class Failed"

How do I convert these values into a range?

Comment: Your code should work if `TextBox1.Value` contains a number. It does not matter that the number is in string format, because it will be converted to a string anyway by VBA to concatenate it with `"A"`. So, either there is not sheet by the name `"Sheet1"` or `TextBox1.Value` does not contain a valid positive number (without decimals).

Comment: Is Sheet1 active? If not, the code will fail.

Comment: I specified to activate the sheet first and now it works - its been a long day - Thanks!

Comment: I just want to inform you that Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row,Column) also exists. I often see people use Range("A"&#) for little reason.

Comment: Thanks Cody, I'm actually using Cells(Row,Column) in my final code - This code was just me trying to get the textbox.value to pass in right.

Answer (score 1):

You should look to use error handling for this

```
Sub Recut()
Dim rng1 As Range
If IsNumeric(textbox1.Value) Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & textbox1.Value)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rng1 Is Nothing Then MsgBox "A" & textbox1.Value & " is invalid"
Else
   MsgBox "Textbox does not contain a number"
End If
End Sub
```